# How to Filter Price range in JSON Data : Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter

I want to filter price range between 250 to 800 in JSON Data

My JSON Data :

```
var data = [{
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298",
    "Price": 200
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222",
    "Price": 200
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33",
    "Price": 6700
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448",
    "Price": 600
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8",
    "Price": 4200
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8",
    "Price": 2200
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8",
    "Price": 200
}, {
    "name": "Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8",
    "Price": 500
}];
```

How to do in Javascript or jquery for Price range filter with All browser compatibility

**I am try this code :**

```
newdata=data.filter(function (el) {
return el.Price >= 250 &&
e1.Price <=800;
});
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written in an attempt to solve this yourself.

Comment: you have a typo in your snippet that breaks (3rd line, 2nd column) `e1` should be `el`. Google for monospace fonts aimed for coders, 'Droid Sans Mono' or 'Inconsolata' are nice ones and display similar characters more distinctly (like: `O`, `0`, `1`, `l`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method, which will create a new array with all the elements that passes the condition.

```
data.filter(function(x){ return x.Price >= 250 && x.Price <= 800});
```

If you want to use filter method in every browser you could add the polyfill method (see link) in your code.

---

Another option with basic javascript would be:

Looping trough the array with a simple for loop and test on the price range.

```
for(var i=0, length=data.length; i<length; i++){
   var current = data[i]; 
   if(current.Price >= 250 && current.Price <= 800){ 
      //INSERT CODE HERE 
   }
}
```

Comment: The loop seems faster http://jsperf.com/javascript-filter-vs-loop and http://jsperf.com/javascript-array-filter-versus-loop

Answer (score 1):

Just as you sad it, use `.filter` and shims for xbrowser. jQuery should have that functionality built-in.

```
var filtered = data.filter(filter_callback);
//
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
data.filter(function(i, j) { 
    return (i.Price >= 250 && i.Price <= 800 ); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following :

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function(val,i,arr){
    return (val.Price >= 230) && (val.Price <= 800);
});
```

It uses a JavaScript Native function called [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
var filtered = new Array();
 $.each(data, function (index, item) {
    if(item.Price >= 250 || item.Price <=800)    
        filtered.push(item);
});
    console.log(filtered);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BvTX9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rtWY7/3/)**

Use **[grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/)**

```
var t=$.grep(data,function(val,i){

   return val.Price >= 250 && val.Price <= 800;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter values by using filter() method in array which will return a new filtered array.

```
const filteredValue = data.filter(items => {
      return items.Price >= 230 && items.Price <= 800
})
```